# Using webpack to bundle a custom yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, yeoman-generator

I'm relatively new to Node in general, including webpack and yeoman, so the solution might be simple.

I built a custom yeoman generator that generates html and wish to use the generator in a browser (so html can be generated client side in the browser). I figure webpack could help me solve this solution but I'm hitting some module dependency snags when trying to bundle the generator.

Specifically, I'm getting several errors in regards to missing `fs` modules and issues bundling json files. From my understanding, setting `target: 'node'` in the `webpack.config.js` file resolves the `fs` issue, but unfortunately since I''ll be using this bundle in the browser I have `target'` set to `'web'`. As per the json errors, I'm trying to include `json-loader` like so:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
    ]
},
```

but forwhatever reason, `json-loader` cannot be resolved when webpack is run.

Any ideas for fixing either of the dependency issues?

Comment: did you install it?

Comment: @AKADER fs, json-loader or both? I tried installing both but didn't have any luck (using the commands `npm install fs` and `npm install json-loader`)

Comment: Try it just as `{ test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" }` and not `json-loader`

Comment: you could also try `{test: /\.json$/, loader: "json", include: "path/to/your/sources"}`